# Vertical and horizontal table alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

[image]I am trying to create a 5 x 13 table in which the contexts of each cell are aligned both vertically and horizontally. So far the contents of each cell are top aligned. I have tried to implement the solutions provided to similar questions asked on here but I dont seem to be having any luck. My code is as follows:

```
 \begin{center}
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \captionof{table}{Example.} \label{tab:title} 
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline Iter. & $N$ & $\epsilon$ & $J = r_{f}$ & CPU (sec)   \\[2pt]
            \hline 0 & 7 & $9.71 \times 10^{-3}$ & 1.0125612 & 0.21   \\[2pt] 
            \hline 1 & 13 & $1.01 \times 10^{-3}$ & 1.0125873 & 0.13   \\[2pt]
            \hline 2 & 16 & $8.74 \times 10^{-4}$ & 1.0126011 & 0.79   \\[2pt] 
            \hline 3 & 21 & $5.32 \times 10^{-4}$ & 1.0126056 & 1.03 \\[2pt]  
            \hline 4 & 30 & $3.21 \times 10^{-4}$ & 1.0126099 & 2.34 \\[2pt]  
            \hline 5 & 36 & $9.82 \times 10^{-5}$ & 1.0127022 & 1.64 \\[2pt]  
            \hline 6 & 45 & $5.19 \times 10^{-5}$ & 1.0127067 & 1.19 \\[2pt]  
            \hline 7 & 64 & $4.70 \times 10^{-5}$ & 1.0127143 & 2.15 \\[2pt]  
            \hline 8 & 80 & $7.57 \times 10^{-6}$ & 1.0127156 & 3.10 \\[2pt]  
            \hline 9 & 99 & $8.73 \times 10^{-6}$ & 1.0127174 & 6.56 \\[2pt]  
            \hline 10 & 165 & $9.80 \times 10^{-7}$ & 1.0127176 & 7.98 \\[2pt]  
            \hline  &  &  &  & 27.12 \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could kindly advise where I might be going wrong in my implementation.

Many thanks

Bob.

I have updated my question with an image of the table rendered in TexStudio where it can be seen that the cell contents are aligned to the top of each cell as opposed to the centre of each cell.

Comment: Well, that's not entirely surprising since you're asking for a 2pt vertical space after each row. Is your intention with this to increase the row height?

Comment: Also, your previous questions have had some answers. If they were helpful, please go back and upvote and/or accept the answers. It's the TeX.SE way of saying "Thank you".

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but maybe you should consider using `booktabs` and `siunitx` to produce something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVctk.png, see https://gist.github.com/moewew/1eb8a0331be29ac9e878399ae0ef2e22

Comment: @ Troy, with regards to you first point, yes it is my intention to add some spacing between each row. However, even when I remove \\[2pt] and replace with \\ the contexts are still top aligned. Could you maybe suggest why this is the case? Many thanks.

Comment: @Bob1986 See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852.

Comment: I think Troy is referring to https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @ moewe, Ahhh, I see now! I didnt realise those icons were there! I usually write a comment to the poster to acknowledge their help. I will make sure to follow the correct etiquette from now on! Cheers, Bob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those horizontal and vertical lines are actually quite distracting. Best to get rid of all vertical lines and almost all horizontal lines. That way, there's no need to waste time on aligning the cell contents, vertically *or* horizontally, since there are no reference lines to begin with.

I actually would *not* center the cell contents horizontally. Instead, I'd align the number on the implicit or explicit decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\centering
\caption{Example.} 
\label{tab:title} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=2.0]
                   S[table-format=3.0]
                   S[table-format=1.2e-1,tight-spacing]
                   c
                   S[table-format=2.2] @{}}
\toprule
{Iter.} & {$N$} & {$\epsilon$} & $J = r_{f}$ & {CPU}  \\
 & & & & {(sec)} \\
\midrule
 0 &   7 & 9.71e-3 & 1.0125612 & 0.21 \\ 
 1 &  13 & 1.01e-3 & 1.0125873 & 0.13 \\
 2 &  16 & 8.74e-4 & 1.0126011 & 0.79 \\ 
 3 &  21 & 5.32e-4 & 1.0126056 & 1.03 \\  
 4 &  30 & 3.21e-4 & 1.0126099 & 2.34 \\ 
 5 &  36 & 9.82e-5 & 1.0127022 & 1.64 \\  
 6 &  45 & 5.19e-5 & 1.0127067 & 1.19 \\  
 7 &  64 & 4.70e-5 & 1.0127143 & 2.15 \\  
 8 &  80 & 7.57e-6 & 1.0127156 & 3.10 \\  
 9 &  99 & 8.73e-6 & 1.0127174 & 6.56 \\  
10 & 165 & 9.80e-7 & 1.0127176 & 7.98 \\
\cmidrule(l){5-5}
& & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Sum}  &27.12 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use `S` for the second-to-last column?

Comment: @moewe There is no need for an additional macro layer and counting digits in this column. Of course, `S[format=1.7]` could also be used.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Ah, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Mico, this is perfect! Thank you for your help.

Comment: The sum without the sum line looks a little strange to me. Instead of the space, I would use something like `\cmidrule(lr){5-5}`. The last column looks a little to much shifted to the right, because most numbers except the sum are using format 1.2. Thus, the column could be set with `S[format=1.2]` and the sum could be patched as `\llap{2}7.12`.

Comment: @moewe - For the second-to-last column, I could certainly have specified `S[table-format=1.7, group-digits=false]`. However, `c` seemed a lot easier (and just as good...).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Many thanks for these suggestions. I've added the `\cmidrule` directive and added a "Sum" label next to the total. I also decided to change the header of the 5th column; that way, the optical illusion of numbers being shifted to the right disappears automatically.